# Best practice deploying using CDK, AWS, and Github private repos?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-cdk, aws-code-deploy, infrastructure-as-code

I am not quite clear on the best practices related to using CDK to deploy private Github repos to AWS. I understand that a pipeline should be created by CDK and the pipeline should invoke CodeDeploy to deploy the assets, but beyond that the details are murky.

I also want to understand if for this use case it would make sense to have a separate CDK repo which is responsible for the infrastructure for the entire backend of my project, or if it would make more sense to have CDK code included in each individual component repo. As I will be utilizing a microservice/cell based approach for building out components, the overhead required in adding CDK configuration for each component might be substantial.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of CDK as a compiler that takes a given language and 'compiles' it down to CloudFormation templates. Those templates are then uploaded to Cloudformation by the CDK framework, and run for you when you execute the `deploy` command.

So. To answer your question more directly - if you can figure out how to do it in cloudformation, you can do it. That may involve spinning up a code build and running a script that executes some api calls or prepares a package for an ec2 server that then uses that package in the next step or any number of things.

But remember that CDK synths its cloudformation template all at once, and is only creating the template. It does not run any scripts that may be part of your code builds, and it does not 'wait' for certain things to be complete - because it isn't doing anything like that. If you have a sequence of events that need to occur, you want to use CodePipeline to orchestrate those events for you - but you can set up your CodePipeline with CDK for certain!

As for Overhead, maybe at first. But trust me when I say it becomes very quick and easy to generate a CDK stack for a given microservice with experience, and its super handy. Being able to spin up an ad-hoc on demand testing environment is super useful. Being able to deploy individual stacks on demand and make quick changes with just a line of code is handy as all get out. Having a single source of code for both your prod and development environments that you make a change in one and on next deployment in each is automatically reflected is super handy.

CDK is a very powerful tool - but it is a very low level one. It creates the template that will create your resources. Thats it. If your resources need to do something after being created for something else to happen you have to make use of other services to orchestrate that (CodePipeline, StepFunctions, Cloudwatch Events, ect)